Kotlin - Collision between ball and walls
I could use help how to solve my issue of ball not fully bouncing of walls of my maze. The ball will go inside the walls, but won't be able to pass through them completely, bouncing from inside. Below I provide code of my app:
MainActivity.kt
`package com.example.mazeball

import android.app.Activity
import android.hardware.Sensor
import android.hardware.SensorEvent
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener
import android.hardware.SensorManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.DisplayMetrics
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlin.math.max
import kotlin.math.min

class MainActivity : Activity(), SensorEventListener {

    private lateinit var sensorManager: SensorManager
    private var accelerometer: Sensor? = null
    private lateinit var btnRestart: Button
    private lateinit var mDrawable: ImageView
    private lateinit var mazeView: MazeView
    private lateinit var darkOverlay: View
    private lateinit var youWonText: TextView
    private lateinit var btnRestartGame: Button
    private lateinit var finishLine: ImageView

    companion object {
        var x = 0
        var y = 0
    }

    private var velocityX = 0f
    private var velocityY = 0f
    private val DAMPING_FACTOR = 0.65f
    private val BOUNCE_REDUCTION_FACTOR = 0.5f
    private val SPEED_REDUCTION_FACTOR = 0.01f
    private var isPaused = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        mazeView = findViewById(R.id.mazeView)
        mDrawable = findViewById(R.id.ball)
        btnRestart = findViewById(R.id.btnRestart)
        darkOverlay = findViewById(R.id.darkOverlay)
        youWonText = findViewById(R.id.youWonText)
        btnRestartGame = findViewById(R.id.btnRestartGame)
        finishLine = findViewById(R.id.finish_line)

        btnRestart.setOnClickListener {
            resetBallPosition()
        }

        btnRestartGame.setOnClickListener {
            resumeGame()
        }

        sensorManager = getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
        accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        initializeMaze()
    }

    private fun resetBallPosition() {
        x = 0
        y = 0
        velocityX = 0f
        velocityY = 0f
        updateImageViewPosition()
        if (isPaused) {
            resumeGame()
        }
    }

    private fun initializeMaze() {
        val maze = arrayOf(
            intArrayOf(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1),
            intArrayOf(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1),
            intArrayOf(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
            intArrayOf(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1),
            intArrayOf(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
            intArrayOf(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
            intArrayOf(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
            intArrayOf(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1),
            intArrayOf(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1),
            intArrayOf(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
            intArrayOf(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0),
            intArrayOf(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
            intArrayOf(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1),
            intArrayOf(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
            intArrayOf(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1),
            intArrayOf(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)
        )
        mazeView.maze = maze
    }

    private fun checkMazeCollision() {
        val cellSize = if (mazeView.width > 0 && mazeView.maze!!.isNotEmpty()) mazeView.width / mazeView.maze!![0].size else return

        val futureX = (x + velocityX).toInt()
        val futureY = (y + velocityY).toInt()

        if (isCollision(futureX, y)) {
            velocityX *= -BOUNCE_REDUCTION_FACTOR * DAMPING_FACTOR
        } else {
            x = futureX
        }

        if (isCollision(x, futureY)) {
            velocityY *= -BOUNCE_REDUCTION_FACTOR * DAMPING_FACTOR
        } else {
            y = futureY
        }

        checkFinishCollision()
    }

    private fun checkFinishCollision() {
        val ballRadius = mDrawable.width / 2
        val finishLineX = finishLine.x.toInt()
        val finishLineY = finishLine.y.toInt()
        val finishLineWidth = finishLine.width
        val finishLineHeight = finishLine.height

        if (x + ballRadius >= finishLineX && x - ballRadius <= finishLineX + finishLineWidth &&
            y + ballRadius >= finishLineY && y - ballRadius <= finishLineY + finishLineHeight) {
            pauseGame()
        }
    }

    private fun isCollision(x: Int, y: Int): Boolean {
        val cellSize = mazeView.width / mazeView.maze!![0].size
        val mazeX = x / cellSize
        val mazeY = y / cellSize
        return mazeY in mazeView.maze!!.indices && mazeX in mazeView.maze!![mazeY].indices && mazeView.maze!![mazeY][mazeX] == 1
    }

    private fun updateImageViewPosition() {
        mDrawable.y = y.toFloat()
        mDrawable.x = x.toFloat()
    }

    private fun pauseGame() {
        isPaused = true
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this)
        darkOverlay.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        youWonText.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        btnRestartGame.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    private fun resumeGame() {
        isPaused = false
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME)
        darkOverlay.visibility = View.GONE
        youWonText.visibility = View.GONE
        btnRestartGame.visibility = View.GONE
        resetBallPosition()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (!isPaused) {
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME)
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this)
    }

    override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {
        if (!isPaused) {
            event?.let {
                if (it.sensor.type == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
                    velocityX -= it.values[0] * SPEED_REDUCTION_FACTOR
                    velocityY += it.values[1] * SPEED_REDUCTION_FACTOR

                    checkMazeCollision()
                    handleScreenCollisions()
                    updateImageViewPosition()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun handleScreenCollisions() {
        val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
        windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
        val screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels
        val screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels

        val maxX = screenWidth - mDrawable.width
        val maxY = screenHeight - mDrawable.height

        if (x < 0 || x > maxX) {
            x = max(0, min(x, maxX))
            velocityX *= -1 * DAMPING_FACTOR
        }
        if (y < 0 || y > maxY) {
            y = max(0, min(y, maxY))
            velocityY *= -1 * DAMPING_FACTOR
        }
    }

    override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor: Sensor?, accuracy: Int) {
        // Not needed for this example
    }
}
`

MazeView.kt
package com.example.mazeball

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View

class MazeView: View {
    var maze: Array<IntArray>? = null
        set(value) {
            field = value
            invalidate()
        }
    private val wallPaint = Paint().apply { color = 0xFF000000.toInt() }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
        initializeMaze()
    }

    private fun initializeMaze() {
        if (maze == null) {
            maze = arrayOf(
                intArrayOf(1, 0),
                intArrayOf(0, 1)
            )
        }
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        maze?.let {
            val cellSize = width / it[0].size
            for (i in it.indices) {
                for (j in it[i].indices) {
                    if (it[i][j] == 1) {
                        canvas.drawRect(
                            (j * cellSize).toFloat(),
                            (i * cellSize).toFloat(),
                            ((j + 1) * cellSize).toFloat(),
                            ((i + 1) * cellSize).toFloat(),
                            wallPaint
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

activity_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.example.mazeball.MazeView
        android:id="@+id/mazeView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/finish_line"
        android:layout_width="39dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:src="@drawable/black_checkerboard"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ball"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:src="@drawable/redball"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRestart"
        android:layout_width="98dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="@string/restart"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!-- Dodane elementy -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/darkOverlay"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/youWonText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/you_won"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRestartGame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/restart"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/youWonText"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


I hope someone has idea how can I improve the code to have properly bouncing of walls ball
